# Javascript calling the same function multiple times and only alerting on the last function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, alert

I have a function that calls a callback several times in a row on button click event. In my callback it sends an alert to the user if the condition is met (bool is false). I only want to send this alert on the last function call so it doesn't alert the user five times. Basically, if the function is called 5 times, I filter the first 4 alerts. I have to keep this setup because the way I implement the function makes it easy for the user to input parameters to get back specific JSON key values based on their input parameters (php_script_to_call, key_user_is_intersted_in, index_to_put_into_table) and all this is currently working, i am getting back desired JSON keys.

```
var boolean = false;
var exeCount = 0;
function exeCtCoreAPI(api, key, index, callback) {
    exeCount++;
    $.ajax({ // filter data, gets the desired JSON key here, and sends it to the callback with three parameters }); 
}


function exeCtCoreAPIcallback(result, index, boolean){
if (boolean){
    $('#data-table tbody tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(index).text(result);
} else { 
    alert("Something went wrong! Certain data might not populate");  //only want to display this popup once, on the last function call
    $('#data-table tbody tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(index).text(result);
}

}


//This is how I call my function
       //php script   //key    //index   //callback
exeAPI("getdata.php", "JSONkey0", 0, exeAPIcallback); 
exeAPI("getdata.php", "JSONkey1", 1, exeAPIcallback); 
exeAPI("getdata.php", "JSONkey2", 2, exeAPIcallback); 
exeAPI("getdata.php", "JSONkey3", 3, exeAPIcallback); 
exeAPI("getdata.php", "JSONkey4", 4, exeAPIcallback); 
exeAPI("getdata.php", "JSONkey5", 5, exeAPIcallback);
```

Here is my logic:

I added a boolean and a counter (`exeCount`), and I am thinking that I will need these to filter the alerts. Basically, when button click event is triggered the `exeCount` will be the number of times the function is called. And then I filter out the first few alerts and display the last. I am just having a hard time implementing this logic. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

use a debounce function. check out this:

https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};

var myDebouncedFunction = debounce(exeApi("getdata.php","JSONkey0",0, exeAPIcallback, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for the site info, do you know if there is a way to use my case? I noticed the debounce function you provided seems to work with time.